# Changing the bit depth of audio with VHDL to use a codec

Tags: audio, vhdl, codec, fpga

I'm trying to use the audio codec given in the Xilinx virtex 5 - ML506 board, which  works with samples of 20 bits length. The problem is as follows:
My samples are 8 bits length so I have tried to play them  by setting them on the more significant bits of the codec input (that's codec_input <= my_sample & "000000000000" ). But as result it plays the audio which It was supposed to play (in a understandable way) plus a significant noise.

I have read somewhere that the codec input should be filled with the sample, so I tried it by doing codec_input <= my_sample * "111111111111", but it worked in the same way.

The codec is working properly, i proved it playing samples of  20 bits length, but I need it to reproduce 8 bit length ones.

So if some of you have some advice or any suggestion... I would thank you very much.

cheers!

**EDIT:** I have tried making the sample the LSB of the codec input and it didn't work.

Comment: Watch out for signed vs. unsigned values. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by writing `& 000000000000`. Did you actually try shifting the bits to the left? A more common notation would be `my_sample << 12`.

Comment: I would put the samples in LSBs, why do you use MSBs?

Comment: I found pretty obvious  that making my sample the 8 msb is what i was supposed to do, but obviously it is not. I will try this way.
@likeitlikeit The result of that asignation would be the 8 bits of the sample on the left, followed of 12 zeros (a simple concatenation). Regarding the signed vs. unsigned, I have already proved that is not the problem.
Thanks for replying, I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: "Resampling" refers to changing the sample rate. You are trying to change the bit depth, an entirely different process, so your title should refer to dit depth reduction instead of resampling.

Comment: When going from 20 to 8 bits, keeping the 8 most significant and discarding the least significant 12 is correct (or close enough). If you are getting noise, it could be that the signal level is too low to be adequately represented, or else an ending or sign issue (sometimes 8bit audio is unsigned, whereas higher bit audio is almost always signed.)

Comment: @BjornRoche If he is padding zeroes to 8 bit samples to make them 20 bits long, the zeroes should be padded to MSBs, or not ?

Comment: When going from 8 to 20 bits, the original bits should occupy the MSBs and the remaining 12 LSBs should be filled with zero. @mishr I'm pretty sure you are saying the same thing.

Comment: Hi. Have you checked the audio quality of the 8-bit signal itself? It seems possible to me that the cause of the noise is the fact that you only have 8 bits per sample, which is not much. (CD quality is 16 bits per sample http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Disc)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to:

- Use the 8 bits of data you have as the MS bits
- Duplicate them to the next byte down
- Duplicate them again (presumably the high nibble as there are only 4 bits left to fill?)

Use the `&` operator to concatenate your bits together like so:

```
codec_input <= sample & sample & sample(7 downto 4);
```

I'm not sure that'll sound any better, but I think that's what you asked for.